# How to modify a binary state of a file in python?

Tags: python, binary, edit

I'm really desperated now.
No matter how hard I tried, searched and made different scripts, still I can't modify it the way I need to.
It's simple,
I want to read the first byte of a file, say in binary it's `00 00 00 10`, complement it so it will be `11 11 11 01` , then write it in it's place, so if the file is two bytes for example, it would be like this :

```
00 00 00 10 #First byte
01 10 10 10  #Second byte
```

after the modification it would be:

```
11 11 11 01 #Complement of the first byte
01 10 10 10  #Second byte remains intact
```

It would be so much appreciated if anyone could shed some light on my problem.

Comment: so you are saying you have a file with binary data in each line and you just want to complement data in the first line and leave others unchanged

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Complement the first byte, write it to the file while rest of the file remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is the read-append mode.

```
with open('file', 'r+b') as file:
    data = f.read(1)[0]
    data = (~data) % 256
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(bytes((data,)))
```

Opening mode is `r+b`. `r` is read, `+` means also enable writing, `b` means binary, so the result of reads is a bytes object instead of a string.

`f.read(1)[0]` reads the first byte of the file and extracts that values from the resulting bytes object as an integer (the indexed value of a bytes object is an integer)

`~data` is the negation of the returned byte. Since python doesn't have a real byte type, we use `% 256` to wrap the result back into the 0-255 range.

`file.seek(0)` returns to the start of the file so the next write replaces the first byte. Seek takes an offset in bytes.

Lastly just write the data back to the file. `bytes` takes a sequence of integers in the 0-255 range so we give it the tuple `(data,)`. Alternatively, we could use the integer's `to_bytes` method and skip wrapping like this:

```
with open('file', 'r+b') as file:
    data = f.read(1)[0]
    data = ~data
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(data.to_bytes(1, 'little', signed=True))
```

Read returns a `bytes` object which is an array of bytes. When you access one, it returns the value at each index as an integer. To convert an array of bytes to a single integer you can use `int.from_bytes`. Its arguments are the bytes object, a string `'big'` or `'little'` indicating endianness, and an optional keyword argument `signed` which tells whether to interpret the bytes as signed or not. To convert back you can use `.to_bytes` which is a method on an `int` object which takes three arguments: the number of bytes to convert to, plus the endianness and whether or not to interpret signed data.

So to work with more than one byte at a time, you can `read` a different number of bytes.

You can `seek` to any byte offset within the file at any time before reading or writing. You can also use `file.tell()` to find out how many bytes are in a file before trying to seek or read.

Comment: WOW! It worked.
Thank you so much. I really learnt a lot from your response.Thank you!

Comment: Just another question, How may I extend this to ,say 4 bytes?
I tried file.read(4)[0] and other variants but all gave the same error : TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'bytes' , What I'm doing wrong?